# Setting up a single backup node for an elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

Given Elasticsearch cluster with several machines, I would want to have a single machine(special node) that is located on a different geographical region that can effectively sync with the cluster for read only purpose. (i.e. no write for the special node; and that special node should be able to handle all query on its own). Is it possible and how can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With elasticsearch 1.0 (currently available in RC1) you can use the [snapshot & restore api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-snapshots.html); have a look at [this blog](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/introducing-snapshot-restore/) too to know more.

You can basically make a snapshot of your indices, then copy the snapshot over to the secondary location and restore it into a different cluster. The nice part is that snapshots are incremental, which means that only the files that have changed since the last snapshot are actually backed up. You can then create snapshots at regular intervals, and import them into the secondary cluster.

If you are not using 1.0 yet, I would suggest to have a look at it, snapshot & restore is a great addition. You can still make backups manually and restore them with 0.90, but you don't have a nice api to do that and you need to do everything pretty much manually.

Comment: Hello Luca, thanks for your answer. I do know about the snapshot/restore api but would you be able to comment on the pros and cons of realtime sync-ing one machine in US with a cluster in Europe? Is tagging the node the only way to achieve it right now? (btw the azure link in the blog article seems broken? https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-azure)

Comment: If you mean having a single cluster I'd recommend against it, mainly due to not fast enough network. What you could do though is have two clusters and push data to both if you really care about real-time.

Comment: @Dionysian thanks a lot for pointing out the broken link, it's fixed now!

Comment: @javanna `You can basically make a snapshot of your indices, then copy the snapshot over to the secondary location`. Is there any specific way to do this in `_snapshot` API or do i need to do this with SCP?